ngx-extended-pdf-viewer - Pdf viewer has a gap between tool bar and document when I use s3 Url
I am using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer and originally I was passing in a pdf buffer which correctly would render the pdf in the viewer with correct positioning and dimensions. I decided to instead use my public s3 url as the src value within my template, and when I do so my pdf previewer opens with a gap between the tool bar and the actual document (reference image below). I've tried working with all the properties that ngx-extended-pdf-viewer provides but have not been able to get rid of this gap. Has anyone ever ran into this issue?

<div class="pdf-viewer-container" style="height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;">
  <ng-container *ngIf="pdf; else errorTemplate">
    <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer
      [src]="pdf"
      [customToolbar]="additionalButtons"
      [height]="'auto'"
      [textLayer]="true"
      [showHandToolButton]="true"
      [zoom]="'100%'"
      [page]="pageNumber"
    >
    </ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #errorTemplate>
    <p>Failed to load the PDF. Please try again later.</p>
  </ng-template>
</div>

enter image description here
I have tried setting the [height] property to different values but his is just the height of the container, not of the actual position of the document. I also noticed that there is a nested tag that has a css style "top" set to 111px, that when I get rid of in the inspector tools it gets rid of the gap, however I can't access this issue from my code.
